# Magnolia tree lost a lot of leaves / is having issues

Tags: trees, tree-care

Does anyone know why this recently-planted magnolia tree may not be doing well and what can be done about it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to know what part of the world you are in so work out the weather there, but a couple of questions instead - how long ago was it planted, exactly? How much and how often are you watering it? Is it in a sunny situation, or in shade? Did you amend the soil prior to planting with anything such as composted manure or garden compost?

If it was planted very recently, then you have bought a mature shrub - these are somewhat more difficult to get settled into their new situation, and need copious and frequent amounts of water. If the tree is in a sunny spot, that means it will need even more care, particularly as magnolias prefer partial shade. More information might lead to a better answer...

Comment: Magnolias do like water , especially in full sun. They do lose leaves but that is too many losses at one time , but still viable.

Comment: South Central US. I don't know timing exactly but more than 1 month and less than 2. Almost full sun other than a few hours at the end of the day.  Was being watered by lawn sprinklers. Not sure what was done to the soil when they planted it. Thanks

Comment: Lawn sprinkler isn't enough really - it needs probably 5 gallons a day directly around the base until late fall/autumn when the weather turns. It  will have a large rootball, and its necessary for all of it to get enough water, so down to what, 8 inches deep? a lawn sprinkler is not going to do that...